# How to retrieve SenderEmailAddress from each mail item in an Outlook folder?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to pull the sender's email address from every email in an inbox folder

I am not having any problems until I reach my `For` command for each email in the folder.

If I use the code as it is now I run into an error because `olSender` is not `Dim` `As Variant`, but if I change it to `Dim` `As Variant` I cannot `Dim` it as an `Outlook.MailItem` to retrieve the `senderEmailAddress`.

I'm assuming a nested `For` loop is the solution. Outlook 2013 is the version.

```vb
Sub ExportToExcel()
    'EXCEL
    'Opening Excel workbook
     
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    
    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    oXLApp.Visible = True
    
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\******\Documents\******.xlsm")
    Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    oXLws.Range("A" & 1).Select
    'OUTLOOK
     
    'Opening Outlook folder
     
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
       
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objOwner = olNS.CreateRecipient("*********@email.com")
    objOwner.Resolve
           
    If objOwner.Resolved Then
        Set BouncedEmailsFolder = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox).Folders("Bounced Emails")
    End If
     
    Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim olSender As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set olItms = BouncedEmailsFolder.Items
     
    olItms.Sort ("Subject")
    
    i = 1
    
    For Each olSender In olItms
        oXLws.Select
        oXLws.Cells(i, 1).Select
        oXLws.Cells(i, 1).Value = olSender.SenderEmailAddress
        i = i + 1
    Next olSender
    
    Set BouncedEmailsFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `If Item.Class = olMail Then` after for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me when set to my default inbox.
`olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`

I wonder if you're not coming across non-mail items in your bounced emails?  You may want to try the code below, which will retrieve mail items only (instead of also trying to extract the sender for meeting requests, task assignments, etc):

```
  For Each olSender In olItms
        If TypeOf olSender Is MailItem Then
            oXLws.Select
            oXLws.Cells(i, 1).Select
            oXLws.Cells(i, 1).Value = olSender.SenderEmailAddress
            i = i + 1
        End If
     Next olSender
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Ryan. I tried your code, but am still running into an issue once the code reaches Next olSender. When I dim olSender as Variant I no longer have an issue with Next olSender, but I then have an issue because I dimmed as Variant it cannot also be dimmed as Outlook.MailItem.

Comment: I just tried it on my own default folder inbox and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can declare the unknown items in the BouncedEmailsFolder as Objects, rather than Variant. Once you determine the TypeOf item is a mailtem you can look at properties that are valid for that TypeOf item.